# Conectar no banco sql um banco postgres

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, postgresql, conexão

Cenário: Tenho o banco postgres A, porém preciso conectar no banco A a partir do sql server 2017.

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Pesquise na web por `linked server postgresql`

Comment: Tem esse PDF que pode seguir para fazer o Linked Server entre os BD, [acesse aqui](https://pessoalex.files.wordpress.com/2011/07/linked-server-entre-o-sqlserver-e-o-postgresql.pdf)

Comment: Você também consegue acessar tabelas do SQL Server no postgres com a extensão `tds_fdw` https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw

Answer (score 1):

Opa, consegui attravés deste guide aqui...

Obrigado a todos pela atenção.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3662/sql-server-and-postgresql-linked-server-configuration--part-2/